# How to save state of Radio buttons in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using a Map to store the state of radio buttons, but I'm having issues saving/updating it correctly when the user makes a selection. Basically my `Map` looks like this:

```
{
    "Group A": [
        {
            "label": "Mark",
            "value": "mark"
        }
    ],
    "Group B": [
        {
            "label": "Steve",
            "value": "steve"
        }
    ]
}
```

If user makes a selection simply update the new selection as the ONLY element of each array because radio buttons cannot have 2 selected values, at least per group.

I'm able to print the Map just fine, but having the following issues:

**1)** For some reason I need to click twice to select an option within the same group.

**2)** When I change options it adds the new selected option into my array instead of replacing it with the new selection.

Here's my live [**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-v47c2s?file=/src/components/ListPage.tsx)

and this is the setter that handles the onChange function:

```
const handleRadiobuttonChange = (field, isChecked) => {
    setCheckboxStates((prevState) => {
      const next = new Map(prevState);
      const a = isChecked
        ? [
            ...(next.get(post.label) ?? []),
            { label: field.name, value: field.value }
          ]
        : next.get(post.label)?.filter((o) => o.label !== field.name);
      a.length ? next.set(post.label, a) : next.delete(post.label);
      return next;
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click twice problem is probably because of how your state updates are happening asynchronously. Your current state isn't immediately available after you call setCheckboxStates.

Also your current logic is pushing the new selected option into the existing array. That's why you're seeing the new option added to the list instead of replacing the old one.

I have forked your codesandbox and changed the required area:

```
const handleRadiobuttonChange = (field, isChecked) => {
  setCheckboxStates((prevState) => {
    // Clone previous state
    const next = new Map(prevState);
    
    // If it's checked, update the array to ONLY contain the new value
    if (isChecked) {
      next.set(post.label, [{ label: field.name, value: field.value }]);
    }

    return next;
  });
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-helloworld-forked-m829h8?file=/src/components/Post.tsx